# <a href> Breaks Text Formatting

Tags: html, css

So I've searched far and wide but cannot find a solution to this strange, strange problem.  I've got some totally standard HTML and CSS but it just doesn't work for some reason when I put it in context.  Observe:

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 2vw;

 font-family: "Roboto Condensed Light", sans-serif;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav {
 position: fixed;
 top: 72px;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 384px;
 
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align:center;
 letter-spacing: 7px;
 
 opacity: .75;
 
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 12px black;
 
 z-index: 10;
 
 /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {background:black}
```

```html
<p class="nav">
   
   <a href="#">MUSIC</a> VIDEO PHOTO ABOUT
   
  </p>
```

This is all the code relevant to the point at hand.  I've got an incredibly simple navigator in the works that's just links in a p (it looks right in context).  If you run the snippet, you see this works just as it should.  However, when in the page:

[image]

any text surrounded by an `<a>` snaps to the position of the first untagged word and gets all overlap-y.

[I've uploaded a super-alpha version of the site-in-progress](http://theundominated.tk/nindex.html) for surrounding code reference and to see the weirdness in action.

I've probably just made some dumb mistake but I've been pouring over this for a while and can't find anything wrong with it, and the fact that it works in a fiddle just confuses me more.  This happens with all browsers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem is elsewhere, the code you post here works (press the "Run code snippet" button). It seems like link is floated or positioned, but nothing of this is in your code above.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page where this is happening?

Comment: Kindly provide code where this happening.

Comment: [http://theundominated.tk/nindex.html](http://theundominated.tk/nindex.html)

Sorry, didn't cross my head to give a full thing for some reason.

Comment: Also this is super-duper-alpha, keep that in mind.

Comment: You need to put enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself. It's no good depending on an external site that you are going to fix in order to explain the problem.

Comment: try adding position: relative; to a tag.

Comment: Absolutely positioning everything without a reason creates too much overhead - bad practice in general.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the input.  I'll make better any questions in the future and also rework the CSS I have currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule on line 7 put absolute position to link, not text-content. It the issue.

```
* {position: absolute;}
/* maybe you thought body > * {...} - position absolutely all 'top' elements */
```

First option is to define elements (`.header, .nav {position: absolute;}`), which has to be positioned.

The second one, the hotfix, is to overwrite the absolute position for links (or nav links). Just add

```
a {position: static}
```

OR

```
.nav a {position: static}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem :)

```
.nav a{
    position:initial;
}
```

Just put this after `.nav{}` and will work fine.

**CSS**

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2vw;

    font-family: "Roboto Condensed Light", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 72px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 384px;

    font-size: 14px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing: 7px;

    opacity: .75;

    text-shadow: 0px 0px 12px black;

    z-index: 10;

    /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
.nav a{
        position:initial;
    }
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {background:black}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="nav">
    <a href="#">MUSIC</a> VIDEO PHOTO ABOUT
</p>
```